# python + matplotlib: barh plot show incomplete YTick labels - how to dynamically move the plot area to the right to fit the given YTickLabels?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I'm using `matplotlib` to plot a `barh` plot to a file. Unfortunate, the YTickLaels are a bit too long and the plot area won't move to the right automatically. Is there a way to move the plot area to the right automatically so I won't have problems with incomplete YTickLabels?

The code I use is the following:

```
import matplotlib as mpl
mpl.use('Agg')
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
D = {u'Label1':26, u'Label2 is longer than others': 17, u'Label3 is not so short either':30}
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(5.5,3),dpi=300)
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.grid(True,which='both')
bar = ax.barh(range(1,len(D)+1,1),D.values(),0.4,align='center')
plt.yticks(range(1,len(D)+1,1), D.keys(), size='small')
fig.savefig('D_bar.png')
```

Here is the output: 
[image: output of barh]

How can I fix this? Thanks

Comment: Doesn't [this example](http://matplotlib.org/examples/axes_grid/make_room_for_ylabel_using_axesgrid.html) help?

Answer (score 8):

Actually, there is an automatic way of doing this now: [`tight_layout`](http://matplotlib.org/users/tight_layout_guide.html).

In your case:

```
import matplotlib as mpl
mpl.use('Agg')
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
D = {u'Label1':26, u'Label2 is longer than others': 17, 
     u'Label3 is not so short either':30}
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(5.5,3),dpi=300)
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.grid(True,which='both')
bar = ax.barh(range(1,len(D)+1,1),D.values(),0.4,align='center')
plt.yticks(range(1,len(D)+1,1), D.keys(), size='small')
fig.tight_layout() # <---- ADD THIS
fig.savefig('D_bar.png')
```

Comment: if you pass the kwarg `tight_layout` to `plt.figure` it auto-magically works as well (but that might be a 1.3.x feature)

Comment: Calling `tight_layout` in either way mentioned does prevent clipping off the labels, but it makes the plot narrower. How would I keep the labels and the plot size, knowing that I would have a really wide png file?

Answer (score 1):

According to [matplotlib mailing list](http://matplotlib.1069221.n5.nabble.com/plot-cuts-off-long-tick-labels-td19890.html), there is no automatic way of doing this. However, you can manually ajdust subplot padding by using [`figure.subplots_adjust`](http://matplotlib.org/api/figure_api.html#matplotlib.figure.Figure.subplots_adjust) method. Placing `fig.subplots_adjust(left = 0.4)` after `ax = fig.add_subplot(111)` in your code yields following result:

[image]