# Some texts cannot be fully displayed while drawing histograms

Tags: python, matplotlib, histogram

I use python to draw histogram fetching data from file 'data.txt' using the following code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from pylab import *

pos = []
val = []
name = []
fd = open('data.txt')
i = 0
for line in fd:
    a = line.split()
    if len(a) < 2:
        continue
    name.append(a[0])
    x = float(a[1])
    val.append(x)
    pos.append(i + 0.5)
    i += 1
fd.close()

plt.figure(1)
rects = barh(pos, val, align='center')
plt.yticks(pos, name)
plt.title('My Diagram I')
plt.savefig('a.png')
```

And the contents of data.txt are:

```
LABEL_001_AAA                       15.365
LABEL_0027                          8.640
LABEL_CEVZX                         1.639
LABEL4                              4.064
LABEL_NV_0                          4.032
LABEL_7                             10.032
```

But the output picture has some of the texts out of the left edge and cannot be fully displayed.
How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: Have a look at this [very similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16011573/python-matplotlib-barh-plot-show-incomplete-ytick-labels-how-to-dynamically).

Comment: Can you edit your question to have the data embedded in it?  It makes life much easier for people trying to help you if they can just copy-and-past your code to get a working example.